# VSTS - Error MSB3202: The project file "..\Master\Master.sqlproj" was not found

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild-task

All,

I set up MS Build TASK on VSTS that would work on a Git Repo containing a SSDT project.

When I run this task, I get the below error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(283,5): Error MSB3202: The project file "..\Master\Master.sqlproj" was not found.

Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

ANy idea what this error could be?

Gopi

Comment: Can you share your build task from vsts?